# Appropriate PERMANOVA (adonis) call for Subject Identity? (Terms drop in output)

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, permutation-test, vegan

I am working with a dataset of microbial species abundances at time points (baseline, 8h, 24h, 48h, 72h, 96h, 120h) for 23 subjects and have weighted unifrac, unweighted unifrac, and Bray-curtis dissimilarity matrices. Of the 23 subjects (variable name = SubjectString), 8 are infected and 15 are healthy. I am looking to find an appropriate call to determine the effect of SubjectString. Originally this is the call I was using and expected results for Infection, SubjectString, and their interaction:

```
adonis(dm~SubjectString*Infection,data=map,permutations=999)
Call:
adonis(formula = dm ~ SubjectString * Infection, data = map,         permutations = 999) 

Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

               Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)    
SubjectString  22    7.9834 0.36288  2.4309 0.34619  0.001 ***
Residuals     101   15.0771 0.14928         0.65381           
Total         123   23.0604                 1.00000           
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, SubjectString drops out of the results (I believe this has something to do with unequal DFs...). For my knowledge, why exactly is this? And importantly, is there an appropriate call / test to investigate SubjectString?

Any insight is appreciated.. I am relatively new to PERMANOVA and every time I find myself studying it I become increasingly confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Infection` and `subject` are linearly dependent; if I'm estimating a separate mean for each subject, knowing whether or not they were infected tells me nothing new, there is no additional variation in the response that `Infection` can add. In R's terminology the main effect and interaction of `Infection` with `SubjectString` are **aliased** and it is not possible to estimate their effect once we include `SubjectString` in the model.

Why not just include `Infection` in the model and restrict permutations within levels of `SubjectString` (something like)

```
ctrl <- with(map, how(blocks = SubjectString, nperm = 999))
adonis(dm ~ Infection, data = map, permutations = ctrl)
```

Comment: I have played with using strata; however, I am trying to find the appropriate test to determine the amount of variation explained by SubjectString ...

Comment: Then you can't include both `SubjectString` and `Infection` into the model. Once you know `SubjectString`, there is nothing new that `Infection` can bring to the table - the `Infection` part is simply not identifiable given `SubjectString`.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks for your explanation! Looks like need to look into simply excluding infection from the model or other options.